# Bootstrap Tabs not working properly in Java/SpringBoot App

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, tabs

This should be very simple, I've used modals and bootstrap in javascript apps and never struggled with this. 
In this java app, I have a modal that opens and has bootstrap tabs to toggle certain content when the respective link/tab is clicked. All content for all three tabs are showing and When the link is clicked it is just adding the href to the url instead of changing the content.... any idea why this is happening and why the content is not showing up? I don't want the href/id's appended to the url as the url wont change because its in a modal.

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" data-izimodal-title="Add Document">
        <div class="row" style="padding:0 25px;">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#newRequiredDocForm" >Required Documentation </a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#newLicenseForm">License</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#newInsuranceForm">Insurance </a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="newRequiredDocForm" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>required doc tab content</p>
                </div>
                <div id="newLicenseForm" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>licences tab content</p>
                </div>
                <div id="newInsuranceForm" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>insurance tabs content</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Any one help on this? I have also same issue.

Comment: Never got it to work, sorry @New-Learner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Stacie I got the solution for this issue. First I added this class to anchor tag but when I added class to li then its work perfectly in my case.

```
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill">
                <li class="nav-item nav-link active "><a href="#newRequiredDocForm" class="active" data-toggle="tab" style="font-size:1.0rem">RequiredDoc</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-link "><a href="#newLicenseForm" class="active" data-toggle="tab" style="font-size:1.0rem" disabled="disabled">License</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-link "><a href="#newInsuranceForm" class="active" data-toggle="tab" style="font-size:1.0rem">Insurance</a></li>
      </ul>
```